# Conversion error?

Tags: ruby, extended-ascii

If I try `255.chr`, Ruby returns `"\xFF"`. Why is `"\xff".ord` returning `160` (0xA0)? I'm using IronRuby 2.0.0p451 on Windows 7 (64-bit)

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: I am getting error for `"\xff".ord`.. in Ruby 2.1

Comment: @ArupRakshit me too, either `invalid byte sequence` or `255` depending on the encoding

Answer (score 0):

Not for me:

```
root@xxxxxxx:~# irb
2.1.0 :001 > "\xff".ord
 => 255
2.1.0 :002 > 255.chr
 => "\xFF"
2.1.0 :003 > "\xFF".ord
 => 255
2.1.0 :004 >
```